# After installing microsoft.aspnet.core through nuget, all my packages got NU1002 error, what's wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

At first, I built up a ASP.NET5/MVC6 project with .netcore in VS2015 community, everything was OK. With going deeper and deeper. I have to use session or tempdata, but after I add **microsoft.netcore.session** package, package restore will fail and  all my existing package got **NU1002** error said: **NU1002 the dependency XXXX in project XXXX does not support framework DNX, version=v4.5.1.** Like the picture. 
[Error on all packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ0R2.png)

But if I uninstall the session package, eveything is OK. What's wrong with this ? My sdk version in global.json is 1.0.0-rc1-update1 and I have removed DNX5.0 from project.json. Does anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot you are using DNX framework in your project, which should be the old version ASP.NET 5 project framework. After ASP.NET 5 upgrade to .NET Core, the framework is now called .NETCoreApp. And the SDK version now is 1.0.0-preview2-003121. The error message also means the dependency does not support framework DNX. I have installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session package successful in my Visual Studio 2015 with latest .NET Core SDK version.
[image]

So I suggest you download the latest .NET Core SDK installer from below link and then create a new .NET Core application and then move your original project files to the new project and then install the session package.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

If your project is create by ASP.NET 5 RC1 project template, please refer to following article to migrate it to ASP.NET Core 1.0.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html